# Reading headers from urllib.request.urlopen

Tags: python-3.x, http-headers, urllib

I've searched for and found many answers, unfortunately all Python2-related, which looks something like this:

```
r = urllib.urlopen(url)
headers = r.info()
print(headers.getheader('Content-Disposition'))
```

However this doesn't seem to work with Python3. There is no `.getheader()` method. All the header data is inside `r.info()._headers` as a list of tuples. The underscore may suggest that this isn't to be accessed directly, or there's a more "proper" way of reading the headers... if so, what is the proper way of reading the headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If **url** uses *http* or *https* scheme **r** is of type *http.client.HTTPResponse*. You can get headers that way:

```
import urllib.request

r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
print(r.getheaders())
print(r.getheader('Content-Disposition'))
```

You can use `print(dir(r))` to list attributes of r.